# How to validate a locale in java?

Tags: java, locale

I read a file in an application that specifies a language code:

```
public void setResources(String locale) {

    // validate locale
    // ULocale lo = new ULocale(locale);
    // System.out.println(lo.getDisplayCountry());

}
```

that must be in the format: `<ISO 639 language code>_<ISO 3166 region code>` eg. en_UK, en_US etc. Is it possible to validate that the locale string is valid before continuing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now I just do:

```
ULocale uLocale = new ULocale(locale);
if (uLocale.getCountry() != null && !uLocale.getCountry().isEmpty()) {
  ...
}
```

which works fine.

Answer (score 27):

I do not know ULocale, but if you mean `java.util.Locale`, the following code may do:

```
public void setResources(String locale) {
  // validate locale
  Locale lo = parseLocale(locale);
  if (isValid(lo)) {
    System.out.println(lo.getDisplayCountry());
  } else {
    System.out.println("invalid: " + locale);
  }
}

private Locale parseLocale(String locale) {
  String[] parts = locale.split("_");
  switch (parts.length) {
    case 3: return new Locale(parts[0], parts[1], parts[2]);
    case 2: return new Locale(parts[0], parts[1]);
    case 1: return new Locale(parts[0]);
    default: throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid locale: " + locale);
  }
}

private boolean isValid(Locale locale) {
  try {
    return locale.getISO3Language() != null && locale.getISO3Country() != null;
  } catch (MissingResourceException e) {
    return false;
  }
}
```

EDIT: added validation

Comment: I think ULocale is referring to [this](http://icu-project.org/apiref/icu4j/com/ibm/icu/util/ULocale.Type.html).

Comment: Just as an FYI. The ISO default delimiter is "-" instead of "_". See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4904803/en-us-or-en-us-which-one-should-you-use

Comment: @BernieLenz right, but the question was about underscore

Comment: Tried isValid and it fails for a locale that was created with Locale.forLanguageTag("abc")

Answer (score 23):

```
isAvailableLocale(Locale locale)
```

Is answer to your question.

**Example:**

```
String key= "ms-MY";
Locale locale = new Locale.Builder().setLanguageTag(key).build();
 if (LocaleUtils.isAvailableLocale(locale))
 {
  System.out.println("Locale present");
 }
```

Avoid using `getAvailableLocales()` it will return you **155** locales Its time consuming.

If possible please explore more at [LocaleUtils class](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/LocaleUtils.html) and [Locale](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Locale.html)

Comment: +1 for this one is more simple than that 5 y.o. aswer above. Thank you so much. I think you can use this whenever you like without concern about high ammount of loop

Comment: but it is org.apache.commons, I dont want to include more libs

Comment: This is the best answer if you already have org.apache.commons included in your project. Also this should be the accepted answer

Comment: Note that the implementation of LocaleUtils.isAvailableLocale() simply iterates through a cached list of locales. The performance is slightly better due to the caching, but it doesn't avoid the linear time search (aka high amount of loop mentioned by @poring91 ). https://github.com/apache/commons-lang/blob/master/src/main/java/org/apache/commons/lang3/LocaleUtils.java

Answer (score 13):

You can get the available locales like so and enumerate them to see if the locale is valid

```
boolean isValidLocale(String value) {
  Locale[] locales = Locale.getAvailableLocales();
  for (Locale locale : locales) {
    if (value.equals(locale.toString())) {
      return true;
    }
  }
  return false;
}
```

Comment: This is very inperformant because of the large number of available locales!

Comment: You only need to do it once and put it into a set

Comment: You could introduce a sorted list with the most used locales, which is checked first and adds new locals if confirmed, this should reduce the checks of the whole available locales!

Comment: +1. If the resources are part of the actual application itself (and not integrated into the system from an external source or interface), I'd integrate the above code snippet into a unit test of sorts that checks all the resources filenames with the list found in `Locale.getAvailableLocales()`.

Comment: What about mixed locales with a language, which is not commonly spoken in selected country, like "en_RU"? It is a valid locale, but one cannot find it in the list of available locales.

Comment: If the system doesn't know about it then you're out of luck I guess. You could I suppose decide to "special case" "en_XX" to default to en_US or something in that case.

Answer (score 8):

use `org.apache.commons.lang.LocaleUtils.toLocale(localeString)`.

one-liner, other than catching `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException`.

Answer (score 5):

[commons lang](https://commons.apache.org/lang/) has a utility method to parse and validate locale strings: [LocaleUtils.toLocale(String)](https://commons.apache.org/lang/api-3.1/org/apache/commons/lang3/LocaleUtils.html#toLocale%28java.lang.String%29)

After that, you just have to check whether the variant is empty:

```
Validate.isTrue( StringUtils.isBlank( locale.getVariant() ) );
```

Answer (score 4):

There are plenty of answers already but for a fast `one-liner`:

```
Arrays.asList(Locale.getAvailableLocales()).contains(Locale.US)
```

In a method:

```
boolean isLocaleAvailable(Locale locale) {
   return Arrays.asList(Locale.getAvailableLocales()).contains(locale);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could check if the String is contained in the Arrays returned by the `getISOCountries()` or `getISOLanguages()` methods of `Locale`. Its kinda crude but may actually work. 
You could also extract all available `Locales` with `getAvailableLocales()` and search them for display names.

Answer (score 0):

```
@Target({ElementType.FIELD, ElementType.METHOD})
@Retention(RUNTIME)
@Constraint(validatedBy = ValidLocaleValidator.class)
@Documented
public @interface ValidLocale {
    String message() default "{constraints.validlocale}";

    Class<?>[] groups() default {};

    Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default {};
}   

public class ValidLocaleValidator implements ConstraintValidator<ValidLocale, String> {
    private Set<String> validLocales = new HashSet<String>();

    @Override
    public void initialize(ValidLocale constraintAnnotation) {
        Locale []locales = Locale.getAvailableLocales();
        for (java.util.Locale l : locales) {
            validLocales.add(l.toString());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isValid(String value, ConstraintValidatorContext context) {        
        return validLocales.contains(value);
    }
}

public class ValidLocaleTest {    
public static class MyBeanWithLocale {
    public static final String MSG = "not a locale";

    private String l;
    public MyBeanWithLocale(String l) {
        this.l = l;
    }
    @ValidLocale(message=MSG)
    public String getL() {
        return l;
    }
    public void setL(String l) {
        this.l = l;;
    }
}

    @Test
    public void testLocale() {
        //success
        MyBeanWithLocale b1 = new MyBeanWithLocale("fr_FR");
        Jsr303.validate(b1); //equivalent to Validation.buildDefaultValidatorFactory().getValidator().validate
        //failure
        try {
        MyBeanWithLocale b2 = new MyBeanWithLocale("FRANCE");
        Jsr303.validate(b2);//equivalent to Validation.buildDefaultValidatorFactory().getValidator().validate
        Assert.fail();
        } catch (Exception e) {
        Assert.assertEquals("[" + MyBeanWithLocale.MSG + "]", e.getCause().getMessage());
        }
    }
```

}

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem recently. With the help from Common-lang I came up with this

```
 public static Locale getValidLocale(final Locale locale) {

    Set<Locale> locales = LocaleUtils.availableLocaleSet();
    List<Locale> givenLocales = LocaleUtils.localeLookupList(locale, Locale.ENGLISH);
    for (Locale loc : givenLocales) {
        if (locales.contains(loc)) {
            return loc;
        }
    }
    return Locale.ENGLISH;

}
```

LocaleUtils.availableLocaleSet() returns all available locales, but it stores the list in a static variable, so it is iterated only once

LocaleUtils.localeLookupList() takes a locale and creates a list with different granularities.

The code basically validates your locale using a more general version until english is used as fallback.