# How to get country code from locale?

Tags: java, locale

I want to get country codes from a list of locale. e.g. I have inputs: en_US, dua_CM, zh-Hans_MO ... I want to output corresponding country code: US, CM, MO... (I am not sure if country code is the last two characters of locale...)

I tried the following Java code, but it printed out null.

```
    Locale lc = new Locale("en_US");
    System.out.print(lc.getCountry());
```

Any suggestions? Thanks in advance!

Dan

Answer (score 4):

Here, you are defining your own `Locale`, for which you haven't specified a Country value (see the overloaded `Locale` constructors).

Instead, use

```
Locale lc = Locale.forLanguageTag("en-US"); // Java 1.7
```

which will get the `Locale` object from [Java's supported locales](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/javase7locales-334809.html).

---

Also, related

- [en_US or en-US, which one should you use?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4904803/en-us-or-en-us-which-one-should-you-use)

(read to the end)

Comment: Maybe I didn't get it, but the OP says _I want to get country codes from a list of locale._ Here you are showing him how to get Locale from a country code, which is the exact opposite

Comment: @BackSlash As I understand it, if you only have the language tag, you need to retrieve the `Locale` to get its country. Or you can build up your own mapping.