# PHP: Get current locale using timezone

Tags: php, timezone, locale

I am using timezone to get exact time of a user according to his timezone. I have a drop down list to select timezone for users and showing their current time as they selected their timezone. The code i am using is:

```
$timezone = 'America/New_York';
date_default_timezone_set($timezone);
echo date('H:i:s A');
```

It is working fine. I want to get locale of that user using timezone in the same way I am getting current time for that timezone.

How can I achieve the current locale using timezone? Does PHP have any kind of solution to get current locale using timezone?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to detect user's timezone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16525617/how-to-detect-users-timezone)

Comment: i want to get current locale like en_US, so it is not duplicate for sure

Comment: When a timezone has more than 1 Locales which one do you need?

By the way these are 2 different things and I think it is not possible!

Comment: the actual one which will be like for us en_US

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Locale and time zone are orthogonal.  You cannot determine one from the other.

- `America/New_York` means that the user's local time is aligned to New York City, which happens to be called "Eastern Time" in the United States, which is 5 hours behind UTC during standard time and 4 hours behind UTC when daylight saving time is in effect.
- `en-US` (or `en_US`) means that the user speaks English, with cultural dialects (word choice, numbers, dates, etc.) of the United States.  For example, `en-US` uses MM/DD/YYYY date format, and `en-GB` uses DD/MM/YYYY date format, but we both call our first month "January", while `es-MX` calls their first month "enero".

I could very well be an English speaking American visiting Japan, thus my time zone would be `Asia/Tokyo` even though my local would still be `en-US`.

Aside: A hyphen (`-`) is the correct character to split language and country codes in a locale identifier.  Though some implementations have substituted an underscore (`_`), [this is not correct](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4904803/en-us-or-en-us-which-one-should-you-use) by the IETF language tag specification.