# What's the alternative options for toLanguageTag() locale method in Java

Tags: java, locale

I am currently using `toLanguageTag()` to get locale code but it gives the locale code which contains dash `-` , my requirement is to basically return the same data but it should contain underscore `_`, is there a way we can achieve it without using `toString()` methods and string replacement?

this [document](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Locale.html#toString()) says use `toString()` for debugging purpose.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4904803/en-us-or-en-us-which-one-should-you-use

Comment: Related: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/325458/parse-both-en-us-and-en-us-as-locale-in-java

Comment: This is far more complicated than it might seem at first (this is often the case when dealing with internationalization). The correct answer probably depends on what you need these locale ids for