# Restrict Language or Locale to certain values

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

We are using Spring MVC ver 4.3 in one of the projects. The application supports i18n and Locale can be changed using url like http://appurl.com/?locale=en 
The problem is when someone sends random value for locale, it is not rejected, rather Spring sets `Content-Language` header value = that_random_str 
And since we are using `CookieLocaleResolver`, Spring also sets localeCookie value to that_random_str.
Is there any way where we can tell Spring to restrict locale values to only few Locales like only English(en) and Hindi(hi) are allowed and `IllegalArgumentException` shall be thrown for other values

Comment: Why not validate this in the same way you would validate any other user-provided input? [How to validate a locale in java?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3684747/12567365) If you only want to support a very small list of predefined values, then it becomes even simpler - use a properties list, or an enum, etc. to provide the set of valid values. Return `400 Bad Request` (and explanation) to the user if the validation fails.

Comment: (Java [does not validate locale data](https://download.java.net/java/early_access/panama/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Locale.html): "_the Locale class does not provide any validation features. The Builder only checks if an individual field satisfies the syntactic requirement (is well-formed), but does not validate the value itself._". Sounds like Spring doesn't either. So, you have to do it.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Couldn't find any standard solution to this so solved it with my own way. 
 I extended `LocaleChangeInterceptor` and overridden `preHandle` method.

```
public class CustomLocaleChangeInterceptor extends LocaleChangeInterceptor{

    private Set<String> validLanguages;
    
    public CustomLocaleChangeInterceptor() {
        super();
    }
    
    public Set<String> getValidLanguages() {
        return validLanguages;
    }

    public void setValidLanguages(Set<String> validLanguages) {
        this.validLanguages = validLanguages;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler)
            throws ServletException {

        String newLocale = request.getParameter(getParamName());
        if(newLocale!=null && !"".equals(newLocale)) {
            newLocale=newLocale.toLowerCase();
            if(!validLanguages.contains(newLocale)) {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("Language/Locale not supported");
            }
        }
            
        return super.preHandle(request, response, handler);
    }
}
```

and in xml configuration:

```
<interceptors>
        <beans:bean
            class="mypackage.CustomLocaleChangeInterceptor">
            <beans:property name="paramName" value="language" />
            <beans:property name="validLanguages">
                <beans:set>
                    <beans:value>en</beans:value>
                    <beans:value>hi</beans:value>
                </beans:set>
            </beans:property>
        </beans:bean>
</interceptors>
```

Though the invalid `Locale` doesn't cause any issue, the security team was persistent that `Locale` injection is possible so I needed to do this.